# Concat elements to a col in a matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A size axb and I loop on each col in this matrix and want to concatenate 3 values before and three values after. I don't know how can I do this?
I'm using this script but its not working, although if I worked on rows its fine where I change `A(:,1)` to `A(1,:)` it works fine

```
temp = [2000 0 0 0 A(:,1) 0 0 0 2000]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp = [2000; 0; 0; 0; A(:,1); 0; 0; 0; 2000];
```

Or, if you want to save some typing:

```
temp = [2000 0 0 0 A(:,1).' 0 0 0 2000].';
```